# How can I counter Saiki's (boss) desperation move?

Tags: king-of-fighters-xiii

I have been unable to hit Saiki when he kneels down. Is it possible to hit him during his desperation move, or do I just have to block and wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't counter his full screen desperation move. Just block.